# Can "Symbol of" spells be thrown at enemies?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The "Symbol of" line of spells (starting at [Symbol of Death](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/symbol-of-death)) state that

> "You can't use a symbol of [whatever] offensively; for instance, a touch-triggered symbol of [whatever] remains untriggered if an item bearing the symbol of [whatever] is used to touch a creature."

My question is: would it be allowed to throw an object, say a 1ftx1ft rock, with a Symbol with a "look at" trigger placed on it at an enemy and have it trigger? Or would that count as "offensive" and not work?

Would it work to have the Symbol on a cloak or other clothing, with the same "look at" trigger?

Comment: Regardless of whether or not you *can*, it's the closest equivalent to carrying around a live bomb you can possibly find. If *anyone* looks at the symbol on your weaponized [something] before you get rid of it, it activates and the first one to roll the save against dying will be *you*, and you just wasted the 5000 gp you could have spent on *raise dead* instead, too.

Comment: This is [famously](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0448.html) the subject of [no little debate](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0449.html).

Comment: #MrLemon Actually "You are automatically considered attuned to your own symbols of death, and thus always ignore the effects and cannot inadvertently trigger them."

Comment: @GreySage Dang that wall of text and my short attention span!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, and the explanation is in the section that you quote in your question.

> "**You can't use a symbol of [whatever] offensively**; for instance, a touch-triggered symbol of [whatever] remains untriggered if an item bearing the symbol of [whatever] is used to touch a creature."

That is a pretty unequivocal statement. It says nothing about *how* the item bearing the symbol is used offensively (except to give the most basic example of how they could be used), it simply rules out offensive use.

> To be effective, a symbol of [whatever] must always be placed in plain sight and in a prominent location.

Unless you can magically target and orient the rock in question so that the holy symbol is prominent and conspicuous, it would be ineffective.

Comment: Would it be considered offensive to have the Symbol on my shield, cover it with a blanket, and then take off the blanket?

Comment: Related to your last line, would it be considered offensive to have the symbol on a rock as before, but face down, then magically (ghost hand or some such) flip it up?

Comment: @GreySage You'd have to take that up with your GM. To me, both of those scenarios have offensive intent behind them, but I'm not *your* GM.